# Mongoose restricted/allowed documents

Tags: node.js, mongoose, underscore.js, lodash

I have a Program Schema which looks like this:

```
var ProgramSchema = new Schema({
  active: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  ...
  user: {
    ...
    allowed: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }],
    restricted: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }]
  }
});
```

If **allowed** isn't empty and the User._id from logged User isn't in it, I don't want to show him the document.

If **restricted** isn't empty and the User._id from logged User is in it, I don't want to show him the document aswell.

My first idea was, that when I get all documents by Program.find(), I loop through each document and check if the document should be returned or not.

But isn't there a better solution than using forEach? Like using mongoose methods and filter documents before they get returned?

---

**Solution**

```
var query = {
 'active': true, //shows only active programs
 $or: [{ 'user.allowed': {$size: 0} }, { 'user.allowed': req.user._id }], //true if allowed is empty or has userId in it
 'user.restricted': { $ne: req.user._id } //true if restricted doesn't contain userId
};

Program.find(query, 'name owner image categories user special', function (err, p) {
  if(err) { return handleError(res, err); }
})
.sort({_id: -1})
.exec(function(err, programs){
  if(err) { return handleError(res, err); }
  res.json(200, programs);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not querying for `your_user_id` in the `user.allowed` array?

```
db.programs.find({'user.allowed': 'your_user_id'});
```